# ЧПУ в codeignither

Tags: codeigniter, чпу

Всем привет.

Есть ссылка такого формата `cabinet/add-proposition`
в CI отрабатывает вот такая функция `cabinet/add_proposition`

В Роуте могу прописать так и все будет работать

```
$route['cabinet/add-proposition'] = "cabinet/add_proposition";
```

Но так писать каждую ссылку сума сойдешь, что сделать что бы было универсальное, что бы - превращалось в нижние подчеркивание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проверял, но это должно вам помочь

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

> Эта опция позволяет автоматически заменять дефисы на подчеркивание в URI сегментах контроллеров и методов, тем самым экономя вам дополнительные записи маршрутов, если это нужно. Это необходимо, потому что не допустимый символ в имени класса или имени метода приведет к фатальной ошибке при попытке использовать его.

Появилось, насколько я помню, в 3 версии.

Или так можно попробовать:

```
    $route['cabinet/(:any)'] = function ($str)
{
        return 'cabinet/' . str_replace('-', '_', $str);
};
```